# Trying to pull data from site, works on most but won't work on this

Tags: php, html

We're trying to specifically pull the dividend data from the nasdaq exchange similar to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18-Y5aLvJxyeF142KgpTq0QpXQkwkrx8ggtHVFuPhmqM/edit#gid=0

Almost every other url works just fine but, the query here doesn't work.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/wmt/dividend-history');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
?>
```

We've been fighting it for hours and decided to finally ask for help. If this is any assistance

```
From strace;

sendto(3, "\26\3\3\0F\20\0\0BA\0045!\232\223\305\251?::\370\207\310\263?\347~\213\325zM?"..., 126, 0, NULL, 0) = 126
recvfrom(3, 0x5561748dce48, 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\24\3\3\0\1", 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
recvfrom(3, "\1", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)     = 1
recvfrom(3, "\26\3\3\0(", 5, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
recvfrom(3, "v\34\t\251\360\370\371B\224s\6O[\7\301[\372\372\365\354\227x\355\351~2\306\2X\210{\220"..., 40, 0, NULL, NULL) = 40
sendto(3, "\27\3\3\0\273\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\322\262(\36\227o#\216\315P\331\255\232\300\211\5\\\236\247"..., 192, 0, NULL, 0) = 192
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 643)   = 0 (Timeout)
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
sendto(3, "\25\3\3\0\32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\371\251tc7\341\t\317\307h\273'\f\321r\3R\331", 31, 0, NULL, 0) = 31
close(3) 

[root@dev01 ~]# ls -l /proc/3/fd
total 0
```

Edit: It's returning no information at all.

Comment: can you update a question and give us a bit of detail on *"the query here doesn't work*". Are you getting any errors ? Is the output empty ? Is the HTTP return code 200 ?

Comment: It works with every other URL that we've tested except that one which throws the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be caused by your CURL_USERAGENT string. When I change it to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.29.0'), the same user agent sent when I curl the URL directly from my server, it fetches the data without issue.

```
<?php
echo "Pre-init\n";
$ch = curl_init();
echo "Post-init\n";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/wmt/dividend-history');
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.29.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
echo "Post config\n";
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo "curl_exec finished\n";
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "http code\n";
echo $httpcode;echo "\n";
curl_close($ch);
echo "Connection successfully closed\n";
echo "Data?\n";
echo $data;
return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
echo "End script\n";
?>
```